# Портирование приложений под старые версии Android (minSdkVersion=3)

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-support-library

Пишу приложение под Андроид, целевая targetSdkVersion=29 (Android 10), все достаточно просто и приятно. Однако меня просят понизить минимальную версию до Android 4, а то и вообще до Android 2. Проект некоммерческий, публикация в маркетах не предполагается, так что на требования гуглоплеев можно не смотреть.

Хотелось бы почитать какие-то уроки или практики о таком бекпортировании, но начав поиск, нашел крайне мало информации, сталкиваюсь в лучшем случае с тем, что советуют использовать родную Саппорт-либу. Саму же Саппорт-либу я не использую в силу определенных причин (и не собираюсь использовать).

Пока думаю компилировать версию под последний СДК, а потом через патчинг байт-кода удалять неподдерживаемые вызовы на младших устройствах. Но, к примеру, `Notification.builder.setChannelId()`, которого нет на старых устройствах, можно безболезненно удалить, приложение и пользователь даже не заметят разницы, а вот если удалить `Notification.builder.setActions()`, то пропадут кнопочки в уведомлениях, чего бы хотелось избежать. И прежде чем изобретать велосипед, хотелось бы ознакомиться с опытом других разработчиков, ведь наверняка кто-то решал подобные задачи.

**Update**

Поясню, почему я не использую всеми любимые конструкции вида:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {...}
```

Допустим, у меня есть активити, примерно такое:

```
package com.example.degradation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.VibrationAttributes;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Home extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String message="Device: "+Build.DEVICE+"\n"+
            //  "SDK_INT:" + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT +"\n"+ -- пришлось закомментировать, так как только с апи4, но это не важно
                "SDK:" + Build.VERSION.SDK +"\n";

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK.equals("some magic version?")){ // никогда не выполнится
            NotificationChannel aa=new NotificationChannel("aa","aa",0);
            message+="Name: "+aa.getName()+"\n";
            message+="Vibration attributes: "+VibrationAttributes.USAGE_RINGTONE+"\n";
        }

        TextView t=new TextView(this);
        t.setText(message);
        setContentView(t);
    }
}
```

Как видим, код под условием, по идее, никогда не должен быть выполнен. Однако, так выглядит это на эмуляторе 1.5:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И его лог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Забавно, но если скомпилировать приложение с обращением к полю `VibrationAttributes.USAGE_RINGTONE`, которое есть только в `Android 11`, то значение 33 покажут и те устройства, где его нету (эмулятор 1.5 и реальное устройство на 10).

Возможно, это как-то связано с используемым мной тулчейном/компилятором (эклипс), что значения полей берутся из линкуемого android.jar, на стадии сборки, а не в рантайме:

```
000458:                                        |[000458] com.example.degradation.Home.onCreate:(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
000468: 6f20 0100 5400                         |0000: invoke-super {v4, v5}, Landroid/app/Activity;.onCreate:(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V // method@0001
00046e: 2202 1500                              |0003: new-instance v2, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder; // type@0015
000472: 1a03 0700                              |0005: const-string v3, "Device: " // string@0007
000476: 7020 1000 3200                         |0007: invoke-direct {v2, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;.<init>:(Ljava/lang/String;)V // method@0010
00047c: 6203 0100                              |000a: sget-object v3, Landroid/os/Build;.DEVICE:Ljava/lang/String; // field@0001
000480: 6e20 1100 3200                         |000c: invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder; // method@0011
000486: 0c02                                   |000f: move-result-object v2
000488: 1a03 0000                              |0010: const-string v3, "
" // string@0000
00048c: 6e20 1100 3200                         |0012: invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder; // method@0011
000492: 0c02                                   |0015: move-result-object v2
000494: 1a03 2300                              |0016: const-string v3, "SDK:" // string@0023
000498: 6e20 1100 3200                         |0018: invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder; // method@0011
00049e: 0c02                                   |001b: move-result-object v2
0004a0: 6203 0000                              |001c: sget-object v3, Landroid/os/Build$VERSION;.SDK:Ljava/lang/String; // field@0000
0004a4: 6e20 1100 3200                         |001e: invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder; // method@0011
0004aa: 0c02                                   |0021: move-result-object v2
0004ac: 1a03 0000                              |0022: const-string v3, "
" // string@0000
0004b0: 6e20 1100 3200                         |0024: invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder; // method@0011
0004b6: 0c02                                   |0027: move-result-object v2
0004b8: 6e10 1200 0200                         |0028: invoke-virtual {v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;.toString:()Ljava/lang/String; // method@0012
0004be: 0c00                                   |002b: move-result-object v0
0004c0: 2202 1500                              |002c: new-instance v2, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder; // type@0015
0004c4: 7110 0f00 0000                         |002e: invoke-static {v0}, Ljava/lang/String;.valueOf:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String; // method@000f
0004ca: 0c03                                   |0031: move-result-object v3
0004cc: 7020 1000 3200                         |0032: invoke-direct {v2, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;.<init>:(Ljava/lang/String;)V // method@0010
0004d2: 1a03 2600                              |0035: const-string v3, "Vibration attributes: 33
" // string@0026
0004d6: 6e20 1100 3200                         |0037: invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder; // method@0011
0004dc: 0c02                                   |003a: move-result-object v2
0004de: 6e10 1200 0200                         |003b: invoke-virtual {v2}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;.toString:()Ljava/lang/String; // method@0012
0004e4: 0c00                                   |003e: move-result-object v0
0004e6: 6202 0000                              |003f: sget-object v2, Landroid/os/Build$VERSION;.SDK:Ljava/lang/String; // field@0000
0004ea: 1a03 3600                              |0041: const-string v3, "some magic version?" // string@0036
0004ee: 6e20 0e00 3200                         |0043: invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Ljava/lang/String;.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z // method@000e
0004f4: 2201 0700                              |0046: new-instance v1, Landroid/widget/TextView; // type@0007
0004f8: 7020 0200 4100                         |0048: invoke-direct {v1, v4}, Landroid/widget/TextView;.<init>:(Landroid/content/Context;)V // method@0002
0004fe: 6e20 0300 0100                         |004b: invoke-virtual {v1, v0}, Landroid/widget/TextView;.setText:(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V // method@0003
000504: 6e20 0700 1400                         |004e: invoke-virtual {v4, v1}, Lcom/example/degradation/Home;.setContentView:(Landroid/view/View;)V // method@0007
00050a: 0e00                                   |0051: return-void
```

И я не очень понимаю, чем отличаются между собой следующие поля:

```
    #7              : (in Landroid/os/Build$VERSION;)
      name          : 'SDK_INT'
      type          : 'I'
      access        : 0x0019 (PUBLIC STATIC FINAL)


    #11              : (in Landroid/os/VibrationAttributes;)
      name          : 'USAGE_RINGTONE'
      type          : 'I'
      access        : 0x0019 (PUBLIC STATIC FINAL)
```

Что в одном случае идет обращение к системному полю, а другое копируется на этапе компиляции/линковки.

Comment: зачем патчить байт код? просто у тебя весь код будет выглядеть как if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {...} esle {...}

Comment: Потому, что если в классе есть референсы на несуществующие классы, то некоторые устройства такой класс отбрасывают. Мне приходилось выносить раньше весь код в классы-обертки, которые я использовал из if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)

Comment: @Yakov, дополнил пост примером

Comment: Все константы инлайнятся java-компилятором - это не зависит от системы сборки, значения берутся, как вы догадались, из android.jar, соответствующего targetSDK или compileSDK проекта. А вот то что, верификатор режектит целые классы, очень неприятно и странно - как они собирались обеспечивать обратную совместимость с таким верификатором?!... Но патчинг байт-кода - это по-моему геморно и чревато ошибками, которые будет сложно выявлять. Лучше уж ветвиться в java-коде с классами-помощниками - и менять код будет проще и глупых ошибок не позволит допустить компилятор.

Comment: Есть ещё вариант использовать препроцессор -  это утилита, которая включается в процесс сборки, обрабатывает исходники перед компиляцией и позволяет ветвиться в коде так, что куски кода, по условию, не будут попадать в сборку. В C/C++ этим никого не удивишь, но в java я видел использование препроцессора аж во времена J2ME - там как раз приходилось извращаться с совместимостью, но при этом экономить каждый байт конечного приложения.

Comment: Ну андроид тот еще callback-hell, это вам не винапи с легаси работающим по 20 лет без перекомпиляции. я думаю у вас проблема с комбинацией android.jar и сдк. вы (образно выражаясь) желаете написать приложение под windows 10, но чтобы оно работало на windows 98 без существенной потери функционала. если "условная" компиляция не срабатывает, тогда используйте рефлекшены (перечислили методы доступные классу, нашли метод, вызываем, не нашли пропускаем идем дальше), по аналогии как это делается 
 в NDK, но вы рехнетесь мейнтейнить этот код.

Comment: еще можешь методы аннотировать через @TargetApi, и они будут автоматом выбираться при вызове. я так делал. правда у меня минимальная версия андроида была 5.0, сейчас 6.1. т.к. в работе куча старых sony с nfc, а заменить денег руководство в Москве жмет. Но приложение работает и на 6 и на 8 и на 10м андроиде. и в результате половина кода костыли, чтобы все работало примерно одинаково в этом зоопарке.

Comment: вот еще способы есть тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526113/java-conditional-compilation-how-to-prevent-code-chunks-from-being-compiled